# GUI freeze when inserting javascript into a WebView in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a small chat application that uses a `QTcpSocket` to communication with my server.

My server sends JSON commands to my Qt chat client which i parse inside of the `readyRead()`. When a receive the command `newUser` the below method is executed. For some reason the below method causes my application to freeze on some machines. Meaning it yields the GUI to become unresponsive. The user then has to minimize and then maximize the application for it to become responsive.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
void MainWindow::addUser(QString channelID, QString visitorName) {

    int exists = 0;
    if (onlineUsers.contains(channelID)) {
        exists = 1;
    }    

    // Add the user to our QWebView
    ui->allVisitorsWeb->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("$('#allUsers tr:last').after('<tr id=" + channelID + "><td>" + visitorName + "</td></tr>'); undefined");

    // Add to active chats QStringList
    onlineUsers << channelID;

    // Display notification
    QSettings settings("MyApp", "App");
    settings.beginGroup("aSettings");
    if (settings.value("visitorNotification").toString() == "true") {
        //displayNotification(visitorName, "Has entered", channelID);
    }
    settings.endGroup();       

    // Added to fix freeze
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Comment: do you know where in that function it freezes?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( It only seems to be on older computers. No problems on newer Macs

Comment: I think the processEvents may be at fault

Comment: Could it be `QSettings` that is causing the freeze? Im thinking cause its accessing the file system